# Command executes when typed, but not when generated?

Tags: windows, powershell

I made a powershell script to generate a ruby command. The command takes forever to execute 
when generated and run by the script. However, when its typed, it runs quickly and gets
the job done. Script logic is :

```
$dat1 = one ruby command | Out-String
# $dat1  will contain the value - rake drive:unit_tests:load_data
$dat2 = "  parameters here"
$dat3 = $dat1 + $dat2
$dat3 = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.NewScriptBlock($dat3)
& $dat3
```

Can someone please help me to figure out why this is happening and how to resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Execute your script using the following command:

```
powershell -noexit "&" "c:\myscripts\script1.ps1"
```

I just got lucky here. Since I am new to powershell, I don't know why this
works. I read one link, but I still don't understand why it works.

http://poshoholic.com/2007/09/27/invoking-a-powershell-script-from-cmdexe-or-start-run/

Comment: This runs the code, but I have to press ctrl+c at each "step" of the code for it to proceed.